# Subscript and superscript need to be align

Tags: horizontal-alignment

*I want to align super and subscript in the display and inline equations*

**It should be:**

[image]

**Now:**

[image]

There are n-number of occurrences in my manuscript, is there any possibility to achieve by a single move.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


$${_{gij}^{bj}\textbf{\textit{R}}}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: [Why is `\[...\]` preferable to `$$...$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917)

Comment: Unrelated 2: why are you using a bold italic R in the text font, not the math font? Probably easier to use the `bm` package and is `\bm{R}` command => bold italic math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\prescript` command, from `mathtools`,  has this alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}

\begin{document}
\[
\prescript{bj}{gij}{\bm{R}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated. Thank you for reminding me!